# How do I get the target of a web shortcut lnk file?

Tags: powershell, shortcut

This is a rather unique issue, I'm finding. I have created a web shortcut using the following script:

```
$target = "http://internalwebsite/subsite"
$shortcut_lnk = "$publicDesktop\usefulname.lnk"
$wscriptshell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WScriptShell.CreateShortcut($Shortcut_lnk)
$Shortcut.TargetPath = $Target
$ShortCut.IconLocation = "https://internalwebsite/1.ico, 0";
$Shortcut.Save()
```

Unfortunately, the target is http instead of HTTPS. I would like to detect any shortcuts that have the unsecure version and replace it with the secure version.

I've found the following code, which is *supposed* to give me the information I need:

```
$shortcut = 'C:\users\public\Desktop\usefulname.lnk'
$sh = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$target = $sh.CreateShortcut($shortcut).TargetPath
```

However, this returns no data. If I just run:

```
$sh.CreateShortcut($shortcut)
```

It returns:

```
FullName         : C:\users\public\Desktop\usefulname.lnk
Arguments        : 
Description      : 
Hotkey           : 
IconLocation     : https://internalwebsite/1.ico,0
RelativePath     : 
TargetPath       : 
WindowStyle      : 1
WorkingDirectory :
```

I've confirmed that the link works as intended. My question now - how do I get the actual web link? If I go to the properties of the link, I see that the target type is the website (http://internalwebsite/subsite) and the target is greyed out with the same info. But so far, my Google-fu has yielded nothing in regards to listing the target type, or explaining why I can't pull the path (or any alternative methods).

If anyone can help I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create the web shortcut in a slightly different way. According to [this TechNet forum posting](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/89fc189d-e7e6-4fe8-b629-8f2cdb53a3b1/how-to-create-shortcut-to-a-url?forum=ITCG), the filename *must* have an extension of `.url` rather than `.lnk`, and you *must* explicitly call the `.Save()` method of the object.

Answer (score 1):

[Jeff Zeitlin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6083222/jeff-zeitlin), thank you, that ended up being the answer for me! I ended up having to do a little more looking to create a custom icon for a URL (uses a slightly different method). Looks like I'm going to have to remove the link and replace it with a URL. I'm using the following script (part of which I pilfered from [a different stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41707358/how-can-i-change-icons-for-existing-url-shortcuts-using-powershell)):

```
$WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
$targetPath = "http://internalwebsite/subsite"
$iconLocation = "https://internalwebsite/1.ico"
$iconFile = "IconFile=" + $iconLocation
$path = "$publicDesktop\usefulname.url"
$Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut($path)
$Shortcut.TargetPath = $targetPath
$Shortcut.Save()

Add-Content $path "HotKey=0"
Add-Content $path "$iconfile"
Add-Content $path "IconIndex=0"
```

THEN, if I want to figure out information about the file, I can use:

```
get-content $path
```

This makes any future scripting against the path significantly easier. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Nice. If you're interested in some background information and a simpler and more efficient alternative to your three `Add-Content` calls, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71770530/45375).